# Word for object that exists in a duration of time

Tags: single-word-requests

I want an adjective for an object for something that exists in a duration of time and not just in an instant or forever. Does such a word exist?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: What did your research show? Are you looking for an adjective or a noun or a gerund or what?

Answer (score 2):

Transient or transitory, as opposed to ephemeral and eternal.

> transient
> adjective   formal
> US  /ˈtræn.zi.ənt/ UK  /ˈtræn.zi.ənt/
> lasting for only a short time; temporary:
> A glass of whiskey has only a transient warming effect.
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/transient